# Show category articles inside joomla article?

Tags: plugins, joomla, components, joomla-article

Is possible show all the titles with links of all the articles inside a Joomla article?

Is there any module, plugin or component that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an "Articles Category" module, and then use NoNumer ModuleAnywhere plugin to include that module in your article using the following code:

```
{module 55}
```

Where 55 is the ID of the "Articles Category" module you have just created. Again, you will need to have the NoNumber ModulesAnywhere plugin installed.